# How do I run my Qt application on another linux machine?

Tags: qt, shared-libraries

I compiled a Qt application on a linux machine using Qt 5.6.2. It runs perfectly on that machine.

I copied the binaries on another 64bit machine. I used `aptitude search libqt5` to find what Qt libraries should I install. I installed `libqt5core5a` and `libqt5network5` packages. But when I run my program, I get this error:

```
darker2:~/workspace (master) $ ./server
./server: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5: no version information available (required by ./server)
./server: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: no version information available (required by ./server)
./server: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: no version information available (required by ./server)
./server: relocation error: ./server: symbol qt_version_tag, version Qt_5.6 not defined in file libQt5Core.so.5 with link time reference
```

I suppose the problem here really is that the version does not match exactly. So, how do I install the very exact version that I used to compile my program? Note that I am very limited with disk space on the target virtual machine. I need to only install whatever is necessary.

The more universal solution, the better, for the sake of future readers.

Comment: There are a number of previously answered questions on this exact topic already, but the _real_ answer is to read the manual: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html

Comment: @MrEricSir I read that page like 5 times. I just don't know what to do if I want to install the qt using the package manager. It also does not say anything about how do I get the correct .so files in the first place.

Comment: I tried the startup sh script as a last resort, but the manual you mention does not even attempt to mention which libraries do I need to copy and from where.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to deploy a Qt application without Qt built from source?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42443118/is-it-possible-to-deploy-a-qt-application-without-qt-built-from-source)

Comment: Give a look at my answer in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42443118/is-it-possible-to-deploy-a-qt-application-without-qt-built-from-source/42564816?noredirect=1#comment73837980_42564816

Answer (score 0):

You need to deploy the application, for this purpose I use the utility
[cqtdeployer](https://github.com/QuasarApp/Console-QtDeployer)

You can install from [github](https://github.com/QuasarApp/Console-QtDeployer/releases) releases

or

from [snapstore](https://snapcraft.io/cqtdeployer)

```
sudo snap install cqtdeployer
```

You can use as follows:

```
cqtdeployer -bin myApp -qmake path/to/my/qmake -qmlDir path/to/my/qml/files/dir
```

And Run application with sh script

If you'll use the version from snap then make sure that you have all the permissions.
[image: cqtdeployer]